# Where can I find the exercise about convolutional neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

I want to learning deep learning,but the material that i can find is the deep learning book which website is http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ , from this book ,what I can learn is the theory about deep learning,but no project exercise,so i will appreciate it if you can provide any material about deep learning exersice,especial about convolutional neural network.

Comment: Get the book or whatever, then make up a project for yourself, then make it happen. Also you can't ask for off site resources here.

Answer (score 0):

[This syllabus](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/syllabus.html) is good. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfnWJUyUJYU&index=1&list=PLkt2uSq6rBVctENoVBg1TpCC7OQi31AlC) are the lectures for this course.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [CS231](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/) course mentioned by Snate above, I also suggest you to look at [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) course by Michael Nielsen. It not only contains good explanation and exercises on neural networks, but also on CNNs.